# Speeding up the process of aggregate function in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, performance, aggregation

I'm conducting aggregate function in QGIS. But since the feature number is high, the process is very slow. Is there a way to speed up the calculation process?

By using this function: `sum("lengths", "ID-1" )`  I aimed to get the sum of the `lengths` field from all features in the layer with the same `ID-1` value as the current feature.

[image: .]

Comment: how is your data stored? is there an index on `ID1`?

Comment: I created by using $id from field calculator. They are integer. There is not an index I suppose.

Comment: then export your data into a databse and add an index to it

Comment: I'm very new in this field. So I'm not sure how to do it. Could you suggest a tutorial or any other thing to follow?

Answer (score 2):

What if you try [a Virtual Field](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#creating-a-virtual-field) with PyQGIS from the QGIS Python Console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

```py
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsField
try:
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant
except ImportError:
    from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant

layer = iface.activeLayer()

layer.startEditing()
field = QgsField('calc', QVariant.String)
layer.addExpressionField('sum("lengths","ID_1")', field)
layer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: I got null results from this function.

Comment: Which data types are your input fields ?

Comment: lengths field is Decimal, ID field is whole number Int 64

Comment: Can you please share a piece of your data ?